# Split JSON Objects MQTT Response Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, mqtt

Is there anyway of splitting JSON objects from a response?

Using MQTT, some of the returned responses are multiple JSON objects in one response. For example

```json
{
    "test": {
        "Subtest": 0
    },
    "test2": true
}{
    "test3": false,
    "test4": {
        "Subtest": 1
    }
}
```

Is there anyway in Swift, to split up these responses and process them as the 2 separate JSON objects that they are?

Thanks

Comment: That is not valid json so you need to write your own parsing code to split the response into valid json messages

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there were any inbuilt swift functions to make that easier? I guess not?

Comment: Maybe but not tested, it could be enough to split on “}{“ or a regex looking for the same reversed pair of brackets

Comment: Good point, as that's exactly the 'invalid JSON' part

Comment: Or fix what ever is publishing the messages to either send just one at a time or to send valid (e.g. an array) JSON

Comment: You could also change your source to use json lines - https://jsonlines.org/. Then you can easily split the lines into separate json documents.